# Chart type to plot only data points

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of response data that I'm trying to plot for clients.  I've had a play with Scatter charts and line charts without connectors but none are really working.  I have a feeling I'm missing something really basic here.  The data consist of a Client Name along with a number of data points.  One client might have 10 data points, another only 1.

Here's a rough example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

**Edit:** Should I start with a scatter chart and modify from there?  Or a line chart without connectors???

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is your current code? What is your problem?

Comment: HI Halvor, my problem is I'm not sure which chart type I should start with and modify to get to the desired result.  Should I start with a Line chart and remove the connectors and go from there?  Or is it a Scatter chart that is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert the axis:

```
chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    inverted: true
},
```

and while placing data you can use x and y axis both values like below:

```
data: [[0, 4],[0,2]]
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        inverted: true
    },
    
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'AT&T',
            'Verizon',
            'Tel'
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of units'
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0
    },
    
    series: [{
        data: [[0, 4],[0,2]]
    }, {
        data: [[1,2]]
    }, {
        data: [[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6]]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" ></div>
```